# How to bind label to checkbox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to dynamically add checkboxes from c# in asp.net. I did that part. But now I want my label to be clickable, but can't find how it is done. Can someone help me?

Comment: Add an event listener to your label using JavaScript?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. ASP.NET is a broad umbrella, for a start. Web Forms? MVC? How about you show us the relevant part that you did and explain how this issue relates to that?

Comment: can you not use some type of repeater or listview for this? A whole lot less work. (and yes, we need to know if this is razor, or mvc, or web forms).

Comment: Sorry i didn't provide enough information. It was web forms, but i will maybe do a multi sect drop list. I think i know how to do it, but thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a check box list. You can easy add "x" number of check boxes that way.

So, this markup:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        CssClass="bigcheck" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And now code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCheckBox();
    }

    void LoadCheckBox()
    {
        // load up (create) "x" number of check box.
        for (int i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
        {
            ListItem OneBox = new ListItem("Check box #" + i);
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(OneBox);
        }
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

Ok, that's ugly. But, lets add a style sheet to this.

Say this:

```
       <style>
            .bigcheck input {width:20px;
                             height:20px;
                             vertical-align:middle;
                             cursor:pointer;
            }
            .bigcheck label {margin-left: 12px;
                             font-size:14px;
                             cursor:pointer;
                             position:relative;
                             top:3px;
                             margin-bottom:15px;
            }
       </style>
```

and now this:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        CssClass="bigcheck"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and we get this:

[image]

Now, we going to use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the checkbox list.

In 99% of cases, you check a box - you can EASY get that item you just checked.

But, when you un-check, then its a bit nasty.

But, this code will suffice:

```
    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // user clicked on check box
        // we in most cases don't need this, and its UGLY as hell.
        CheckBoxList list = (CheckBoxList)sender;
        string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
        int idx = control.Length - 1;

        // now with idx, display status of check box JUST changed.
        ListItem MyCheckRow = CheckBoxList1.Items[idx];

        Debug.Print("Row/index check/unchecked = " + idx);
        Debug.Print("check box clicked = " + MyCheckRow.Text +
            " checked = " + MyCheckRow.Selected);

        // optional - display all check box, and their current check status
        Debug.Print("====");

        foreach (ListItem OneCheckRow in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            Debug.Print("Check box = " + OneCheckRow.Text +
                " Checked status = " + OneCheckRow.Selected);
        }
    }
```

So, check a box, like this:

AND NOTE very close - the label in such controls can be clicked on.

So, this:

[image]

debug.output:

[image]

So, I don't think you need (or should) try to inject "x" number of check boxes. Use the check box list. About the only face plant part of the above code is getting the check box item WHEN you un-check, but once we have the "index" of the changed row, then as above shows, we can get the value of the  checked item (or un-checked).

The other huge advantage? The list can be driven directly from a data source - and thus again, you don't even have to loop to select the values - but feed it a data source.

AND ALSO by default, you can click on the box or the label - that's the default anyway, and thus no need to worry about some separate click event for the label part.